# Declare dependency version with Stackblitz?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, stackblitz

Is there a way declare the dependency version on stackblitz.  I've updated the dependency on NPM, but stackblitz keeps insisting on installing the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened when you did `<package>@<version>` ?

take a look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gu4byu ...where I just installed an old version using "highcharts@6.2.0"... the latest version is 7.0.1

I was also able to install newer/older version of a dependency without any issue